# Remove White Gap in Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to stack images over my background and have them be responsive to the background-image, so I figure that container-fluid would be the best way to do so. But, with the background, there's a white gap on the left and right sides: how do I get rid of it?

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse header" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resume </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">

    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/background.jpg">

</div>



</body>
```

Styling:

```
body {
    margin:none;
    padding:none;

}

/* CENTERS NAVBAR TEXT */
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RyanGross1993/04ybbs2v/1/

Comment: Please add code to jsfiddle.

Comment: At the very least, provide a screenshot of the problem. And what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `border: 0` and `padding: 0` instead of `none`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to set a full responsive background image, you can try this:

```
html {
    background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/6vqm57bb/

For more details about `background-size` please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

I hope this will help.

Comment: It does! 
But, then, how would I overlay an image on top of the background? I'm thinking of using the img-responsive class provided, and media queries for adjustable margins?

Comment: @RyanG Please take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/6vqm57bb/ and tell me if that's what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

only you have to set a div with class `.row`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/12/859723-nature-background.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

also you can use cover for background size.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/eyydxx80/)